# Design of Java Class correct method usage

Tags: java

I am designing a class called interval.

so far I have two atttributes lowerBound and upperBound

now how would I make the interval open by default. I assumed a default constructor would do fine right here

note I havent wrote code I am only thinking of design at the moment

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I have not written the code yet I am just designing it. It is a class so far called interval I have two attributes lower and upper. I just want to know how I would make an interval open by default

Comment: You could make the bounds nullable to indicate an open interval. Also, you may want to have boolean flags for `[` vs `(` (if that makes sense in your domain).

Comment: I wouldn't use the constructor at all. Keep it internal and `private`. Use well named `static` factory methods so you could call `Internal.open(3, 7)` or `Interval.closed(3,7)`. You could even extend that to a fluid builder, so something like `Interval.lowerInclusive(3).upperExclusive(7).build()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Boris, I'm surprised, these days I really shy away from the usage of static anything unless it is final/constants. Not good for thread safety.

Comment: @dlcole what? You comment makes absolutely no sense. You seem to be confusing `static` state with the `static` method factory pattern. In fact this factory pattern is the preferred approach for creating readable constructors. See [Effective Java](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151) and Java 8 [value-based classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html). Dogmatically avoiding things without understand is a recipe for bad code.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the requirements, can only guess.
Lets say you have a lower and upper bound of integer type, you could declare them as Integer and initially allow them to be null. Then provide Constructors, getter/setters to set the values if they are to be bounded:

```
public class Interval{
    Integer lowerBound = null;
    Integer upperBound = null;

    public Interval(){
        super();
    }

    public Interval(Integer lower, Integer upper){
        setLowerBound(lower);
        setUpperBound(upper);
    }

    public void setLowerBound(Integer lower){
        this.lowerBound = lower;
    }

    public void setUpperBound(integer upper){
        this.upperBound = upper;
    }

    public boolean isLowerBounded(){
        return (lowerBound == null) ? false: true;
    }

    public boolean isUpperBounded(){ 
        return (upperBound == null) ? false: true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like this. There doesn't seem any sensible reason to have the internal mutable. This code doesn't have any validation, nor could it due to mutability. Also - why is there a random call to `super()`?

Comment: Well, with the extensive requirements provided, you can call this a simple example. Is there a reason to have it mutable or not? Who knows at this point. As far as the random call to super(), it's hardly random. If you don't declare a constructor, this is exactly what you get - a default constructor that calls super(). In addition, if you want the default constructor, adding the call to super() supports the case where in the future you decide to extend a super class the default constructor would delegate.

Comment: Prefer immutable objects. They are easier to reason about. The question should be "is there a reason to have it mutable" - and the answer here is no as mutability introduces a whole host of validation problems. As to the second part of your comment - you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding. The Java _compiler_ will **always** add a call to `super()` as the first item in a constructor which does not call another constructor or a superclass constructor. Adding it in explicitly betrays a lack of understanding a basic inheritance concepts...

Comment: Yes, prefer immutable objects I agree, you are spot on regarding this. On your second comment - you are way too harsh and brash. To be more specific regarding adding the default constructor: The case where you add a custom constructor, if you need a default, you must then provide your own. In my experience when doing this, it's a good idea to add the call to super because often the default constructor will later be modified and the call to super() will be omitted, not realizing that once you add another line of code within the constructor, you lose the for-free call to super().

Comment: I don't understand your comments re calling super. Either a default superclass constructor exists and is called automatically or it does not exist and you have a compiler error. There is never a reason to call it explicitly.

Comment: You are right in the case of the no-args super(). The only reason to call it explicitly is to invoke super class constructors that have arguments - to 'choose' the right constructor for your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103398/discussion-between-dlcole-and-boris-the-spider).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an interval-class I guess you are going to compare if a value is within the interval. So each edge-point in the interval can have 3 states. It can

1. Be at an exact point   [3
2. Be infinitely close to a point (3 , or
3. Be infinite, or rather undefined.

I suggest making a general class with the values:

```
• upperValue
• lowerValue
• isUpperBounded (boolean)
• isLowerBounded (boolean)
```

You would then have to the logic needed to know if a point is within the interval. If one value was bounded you would use inclusive comparison `=<`, else exclusive comparison `<`.
`Null` would be a case of an infinite bound, since an Interval with only one value really is just a point.

You could then even have:

```
public class ClosedInterval extends Interval
```